# How to change the .xml file an activity uses?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to handle screen-rotation myself and I need to know: How do I tell my activity to use another .xml file for the new layout? I've tried different things but none of them worked.

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not handle it in code, rather, you put your other layout file (with the same name) in the appropriate folder (then Android does the rest).

Like this (pseudo-code):

```
layout_landscape\my_layout.xml
layout\my_layout.xml
```

Link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

try `setContentView(your new xml)`, you should override `onConfigurationChanged()` and act accordingly

Orientation change usually calls `onCreate()` again, and restarts the activity at a new configuration.

make sure you do the following:

**Set the Activity's manifest to intercept orientation change events**

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

**Override `onConfigurationChanged()`**

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
    {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == android.content.res.Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.layout_portrait);

            }
            else if (newConfig.orientation == android.content.res.Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.layout_landscape);
            }
    }
```

And read [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html), it's a great document about faster orientation changing.

Comment: I'm handling it with a menu button (for a reason). setContentView doens't seem to work...